# RS-422 to usb convertor does work but Serial Com port does not

Tags: linux, embedded

I am trying to get my com port working with my device and am having trouble doing so. I have already tested the serial output from my device using a RS-422 to USB convertor and data was being shown on my screen terminal flawlessly thorough /dev/ttyUSB0. My goal is to forgo the convertor and connect directly to my com port, /dev/ttyS0. The problem is when using screen to view my data on /dev/ttyS0 all I get is nonsensical data.

My device uses a slightly faster baud rate of 230400 so I though that might be an issue so I contacted the manufacturer but they stated the com port is capable of high speeds with an RS-422 protocol. I then followed up by doing getting a loopback cable and seeing if Tx matches Rx and it does. Ultimately, I am very confused as to why the RS-422 - USB convertor does the trick but when trying to simply use the serial port I get garbage data.

For clarity, My PC does indeed have a COM port to connect to serially. The bios settings let me pick if the port uses RS-422, RS-232, and RS-485. I have a gps connecting to my device and my device connects to my PC either through the COM port(does not work) or by usb with the convertor(does work).  I expect a steady stream of positional data which I get only when using the convertor. When using the COM port I get random Char/numbers and unkown symbols(�). Only things I can think of is:

A. my COM port is broken(though it passed the loobback test)
B. Missing some sort of driver in order to run with a 230400 baud rate
C. Somehow the convertor is able to translate the ascii characters but the serial port cannot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you very much for taking the tour, this is rare. -- Do you use an RS422-to-RS232 adapter? Or do you have a special COM port interface at your PC? Please show us in detail how you connect the device to your PC. Are you aware that the levels on the wires are different between RS422 and the ubiquitous RS232 serial port? -- You also might like to add some example data and readings. -- Please remember to [edit] your question to clarify, _do not_ write a comment. This is not a forum.

Comment: D. The classic mistake of missing signal ground.

Comment: Your have not specified your target.  I once worked on a system where a 160MHz STM32 running an RTOS was UART connected at 230400 to a 500MHz NXP MCU running Linux.  The vendor updated their distro and removed DMA support from the UART driver and it all stopped working.  The 500MHz processor could not keep up with the data stream using UART interrupts - that's Linux for you, the STM32 had no problem.  Bear in mind that if you are using UART RXNE/TXE interrupts and no FIFO, that will be 43us between interrupts you need to keep up with.

Comment: Item C is non-sense - there is no translation, it is all just bytes - how you present them is a matter of interpretation, `'A'` is only `'A'` is you choose to interpret it as such, otherwise it is just a sequence of bits 01000001 (In MSB to LSB order).  Moreover if either A or B are the case, it is not a question for this site.

Comment: the COM port in PC is actually RS232. While most of board are using TTL serial. In order to communicate between device and PC you need to have logic converter board. The easiest way is use MAX232 circuit. Otherwise, it is advisable to use USB-TTL interface.